# Logging for New Member Role

Tags: discord.js

Below is my code for logging whenever a role is added to a user. I am quite new to programming so I am not sure what I can and cannot try. It is currently not working at all.

```js
client.on(Events.GuildMemberUpdate, async (oldMember, newMember) => {

    message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        type: AuditLogEvent.GuildMemberUpdate,
    })
    .then(async audit => {
        const { executor } = audit.entries.first()

        const oldroles = oldMember.roles;
        const newroles = newMember.roles

        const channelID = '1164406572932415518'
        const mChannel = await guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .setTitle('Member Update')
        .addFields({ name: "Old Roles", value: `${oldroles}`, inline: false})
        .addFields({ name: "New Roles", value: `${newroles}`, inline: false})
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: 'Mod Logging System'})

        mChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    })
})
```

Although I have read through many forums to try and use code from other people as an idea to what I need to do to get this to work, it is not working at all. I tried to use older code from other people but that was just not working at all for me either. Instead of using client.on(Events.GuildMemberUpdate, async (oldMember, newMember) => , I was using client.on('guildMemberUpdate, (oldMember, newMember) and that as well was not working. Not sure how to fix so please point out the errors in my code.

Answer (score 1):

`Events.GuildMemberUpdate` is already providing you with the `oldMember` & `newMember` objects which contain the previous and current roles of the member.

Using `fetchAuditLogs` is unnecessary.

First of, by using `oldMember.roles` or `newMember.roles` you are accessing a [Collection](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods), that you later attempt to add it as a field in your embed.
This won't work as fields take a String as value.

You need to map the collection and join it.

```
client.on(Events.GuildMemberUpdate, async (oldMember, newMember) => {

  const oldRoles = oldMember.roles.cache.map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join("\n"); // or " "
  const newRoles = newMember.roles.cache.map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join("\n");
```

If you want to remove the @everyone role, you need to filter the Collection before mapping:

```
  filter(r => r.id != newMember.guild.id).map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join("\n"); 
  // or by " "
```

The rest of the code should work as intended. Just make sure the `channelID` is correct and the channel exists.

```
  const channelID = '1164406572932415518'
  const mChannel = await guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setColor(0xFF0000)
  .setTitle('Member Update')
  .addFields(
    { name: "Old Roles", value: `${oldroles}`, inline: false},
    { name: "New Roles", value: `${newroles}`, inline: false}
    )
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter({ text: 'Mod Logging System'})

  mChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

)}
```

Lastly, in order to receive this Event you need to make sure that the your bot has the `GuildMembers` Intent and that you have enabled the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` at https://discord.com/developers/applications